# PCI compliance apache versions

Tags: apache, security, pci-compliance

We are working with current version of Apache 2.4.
6 available in a Centos 7 repos. Installed with yum.

and we are dealing with the PCI compliance and the report says:

```
IP Address: x
Host: x
Path: 

THREAT REFERENCE

Summary: 
vulnerable Apache version: 2.4.6

Risk: High (3)
Port: 443/tcp
Protocol: tcp
Threat ID: web_server_apache_version

Details: Apache HTTP Server mod_proxy_fcgi Response Handling Vulnerability
11/21/14
CVE 2014-3583
Apache HTTP Server before 2.4.11 is prone to a vulnerability,
which can be exploited to cause a DoS (Denial of Service).
The vulnerability exists due to an overflow condition in mod_proxy_fcgi.
when handling responses from FastCGI servers. The vulnerability can be exploited by
sending a crafted response from a malicious FastCGI server, which could lead to a 
crash when reading past the end of a heap memory. 
Apache HTTP Server NULL Pointer Dereference Vulnerability
10/08/14
CVE 2014-3581
Apache HTTP Server 2.4.10 and earlier is prone to a vulnerability,
which can be exploited to cause a DoS (Denial of Service).
The vulnerability exists because the application contains flaw in
the cache_merge_headers_out() function which is 
triggered when handling an empty 'Content-Type' header value. 
Multiple Vulnerabilities Fixed in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.10
07/24/14
CVE 2014-0117
CVE 2014-0118
CVE 2014-0226
CVE 2014-0231
CVE 2014-3523
Apache HTTP Server before 2.4.10 is prone to multiple vulnerabilities,
which can be exploited to cause a DoS (Denial of Service).
The vulnerabilities exist because the application contains flaw in 
mod_proxy, mod_deflate, mod_status, and mod_cgid modules and
in the winnt_accept function of WinNT MPM. 
Note: the WinNT MPM denial of service vulnerability can only
be exploited when the default AcceptFilter is used.
Apache HTTP Server Two Denial of Service Vulnerabilities
03/19/14
CVE 2013-6438
CVE 2014-0098
Apache HTTP Server before 2.4.9 is prone to two vulnerabilities,
which can be exploited to cause a DoS (Denial of Service).
The first vulnerability exists due to an error in the mod_log_config module when logging 
with truncated cookies. The second vulnerability is due to a boundary error in the mod_dav 
module when removing leading spaces.
HTTP-Basic Authentication Bypass Vulnerability
08/14/09
Apache 2.2.2 and prior are prone to an authentication-bypass vulnerability 
because it fails to properly enforce access restrictions on certain requests to a site that requires authentication.
An attacker can exploit this issue to gain access to protected resources, 
which may allow the attacker to obtain sensitive information or launch further attacks.
Apache HTTP Server OS Fingerprinting Unspecified Security Vulnerability
11/03/08
Apache 2.2.9 and prior is prone an unspecified security vulnerability.

Information From Target:
Service: https
Received: Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.6.13
```

We update the server once a week "yum update"

but when i do:  rpm -q --changelog httpd | grep CVE i can see this:

- core: fix chunk header parsing defect (CVE-2015-3183)
  and ap_force_authn hook (CVE-2015-3185)
- core: fix bypassing of mod_headers rules via chunked requests (CVE-2013-5704)
- mod_cache: fix NULL pointer dereference on empty Content-Type (CVE-2014-3581)
- mod_cgid: add security fix for CVE-2014-0231 (#1120608)
- mod_proxy: add security fix for CVE-2014-0117 (#1120608)
- mod_deflate: add security fix for CVE-2014-0118 (#1120608)
- mod_status: add security fix for CVE-2014-0226 (#1120608)
- mod_cache: add secutiry fix for CVE-2013-4352 (#1120608)
- mod_dav: add security fix for CVE-2013-6438 (#1077907)
- mod_log_config: add security fix for CVE-2014-0098 (#1077907)

How can I apply the patches that the security scan is asking for?
I cannot find rpms to do it.

Comment: Ask at serverfault: https://serverfault.com/ or superuser: https://superuser.com/

Comment: Yep, they accepted the changelog output but i still dont understand why, becouse not all CVE that they are asking for, are in changelog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redhat [backports](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) their patches, therefore you may have patched apache, but it will still show the old version.  Take the changelog and submit it as proof of a false positive to your QSA, they should accept it and close out the vulnerability.